# Yelp API reservation openings returning "NOT FOUND"

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, yelp, yelp-fusion-api

I'm wanting to use the Yelp reservations API to see what times you can make reservations at a restaurant for. Every time I query the API it returns the following:

```
{'error': {'code': 'NOT_FOUND', 'description': 'Resource could not be found.'}}
```

I'm using the following endpoint:

```
https://api.yelp.com/v3/bookings/QR7JDps9RqH2430JSzasrg/openings
```

And using the following code (Python 3):

```
import requests

API_KEY = '<My key>'
ENDPOINT ='https://api.yelp.com/v3/bookings/QR7JDps9RqH2430JSzasrg/openings'
HEADERS = {'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % API_KEY}

PARAMETERS = {
  'time': '17:30',   
  'date': '2019-08-06',
  'covers': 2,
}

response = requests.get(url=ENDPOINT,params=PARAMETERS,headers=HEADERS)
data = response.json()

print(data)
```

This is the [docs](https://docs.developer.yelp.com/docs/endpoints-4#section-reservations-endpoint) I'm going off of for further context.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: did you get any answer for this??